# PowerShell - Pipeline - hard coded program vs variable

Tags: powershell

I'm fairly new to PowerShell. I've created a variable which contains some data which I then pass on to an email generator:

```
$strEmailFile = "C:\Testing\SomeTextFile.txt"

cat $strEmailFile | E:\sendmail.exe -t
```

My problem is I don't want to hard-code the drive for the email generating software. So I would like the code to be something like this:

```
$strEmailFile = "C:\Testing\SomeTextFile.txt"

$Dir = "E:"

cat $strEmailFile | $Dir + "\sendmail.exe" -t
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline."

Is there a way for me to use the pipeline but not have to hard-code?

Comment: You don't need `sendmail.exe` with PowerShell when you have `Send-MailMessage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [`Send-MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage) but the difference between your attempts is that the first one is an expression, and the second one is a string, and you can't pipe into a string.

But if you use the [call operator `&`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) you could pipe into that:

```
cat $strEmailFile | & ($Dir + "\sendmail.exe") -t
```

Note that you need parentheses to first run the expression that concatenates the variable and the string).

Comment: Thank you that helped. Sorry for the delayed response

Comment: @S.Hasan 3 years later, you are very welcome! Thanks for the note :)